# How to pass variables to other files

Tags: lua

I'm making an addon in Lua and in a config file, I have marked `RankName = "Whatever"`  If I want to then call this back in another file and check what rank that player is, how would I pass this over? Here's part of the config code that I want to be able to pass over to another file

```
TimeRewards:Add( {
    RankName = "Regular",
    TimeRequire = { days = 0, hours = 3, mins = 0 },
    Reward = function( ply )
    ply:ChatPrint( "You are now a regular on the server,     

    ply:addMoney( 50000 )
    ply:ChatPrint( "You were rewared $50000 for achieving!" )

    end
} )
```

I need to use the `RankName()` in a file to check if they are a high enough rank so, `if RankName() == "Regular" then ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a module that could be required on the other file.

here you have some example extract from [modules](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial)

```
local mymodule = {}

function mymodule.foo()
    print("Hello World!")
end

return mymodule
```

on the other file

```
local mymodule = require "mymodule"
mymodule.foo()
```

maybe you could return that values on the modue

Comment: Wow! Thanks dude! It worked. First time posting here and fast response! I appreciate it dude thanks!